# I have an ldap connection on my RoR app but now how do I check users on login?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, active-directory, ldap

I'm developing an `Ruby on Rails` webapp and I'm trying to use `LDAP` authentication to authenticate my users, I have the connection set up and working to the `LDAP`, but now I can't find any examples or documentation online on how to write code to authenticate users against my `LDAP` on `Ruby on Rails`

I'm using: `Ruby v2.2` and `Rails v5.0.3` and the gem I'm using to connect to ldap is `gem 'net-ldap', '~> 0.16.0'`

This is my login form at the moment, authenticating with a `sqlserver DB`, but I want it to authenticate against my `LDAP DB` :

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end


  def create
    user = User.find_by_NumeroEmpregado(params[:NumeroEmpregado])

    if user && user.authenticate(params[:password])

      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
     flash[:error] = "Erro!              \nNúmero de Empregado e/ou password incorrecto(a)"
     redirect_to '/login'
     end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/index/new'
  end

end
```

users_controller.rb

```
class UsersController < ApplicationController

  def new
  end

  def create
    user = User.new(user_params)
    if user.save
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
    flash[:error] = "Erro!           \nNenhum dos campos pode ser deixado em branco"
    redirect_to '/signup'

    end
  end

private
  def user_params
    params.require(:user).permit(:NumeroEmpregado, :nome, :password, :password_confirmation)
  end
end
```

- How can I reformulate this code into authenticating with my `LDAP DB`?

Comment: I think this piece of code should do the trick for you...https://github.com/ruby-ldap/ruby-net-ldap/blob/e4c46a223a19feda78393a793711353aa1febdcd/lib/net/ldap.rb#L37-L51

Comment: Yes, I'm using this code to establish the connection to the ladp, What I want is to login users and check if the domain and username and password are correct with what's on the LADP

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could create a *service* that handles that process:

app/services/authenticate_user.rb

```
class AuthenticateUser
  def initialize(user, password)
    @user = user
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    user_is_valid?
  end

  private
  def user_is_valid?
    ldap = Net::LDAP.new
    ldap.host = your_server_ip_address
    ldap.port = 389
    ldap.auth(@user, @password)
    ldap.bind
  end
end
```

Then use it in your controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    username = params[:NumeroEmpregado]
    password = params[:password]
    name     = "Some Name"      # Change "Some Name" to set the correct name  

    if AuthenticateUser.new(username, password).call
      user = User.create_with(nome: name).find_or_create_by(NumeroEmpregado: username)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Erro!              \nNúmero de Empregado e/ou password incorrecto(a)"
      redirect_to '/login'
     end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/index/new'
  end
end
```

`AuthenticateUser.new(user, password).call` will return `true` when valid `user` and `password` are provided, and will return `false` otherwise.

This is a basic example covering only the LDAP authentication, you will need to adapt it for your specific needs, including exception handling.

Comment: I got this error: `uninitialized constant SessionsController::AuthenticateUser`

Comment: Nvm, I restarted the server, but now it's giving me the `else` error when I insert a valid user from the ad, why is this?

Comment: `@AnroDeodo ldap.bind` will return `false` only if the information provided is incorrect, have you confirmed that host/user/password are correct?

Comment: @AnroDeodo You can use `get_operation_result` to get more details about why it failed. For example, add `puts ldap.get_operation_result` right after `ldap.bind` and check what is printed on the server log.

Comment: nevermind, I had to use my company's domain name `@company.com`, is there a way to define this like `@NumeroEmpregado"@company.com'` ?

Comment: @AnroDeodo You mean to append that domain to each user? If so, yes, with something like this: `@user = "#{user}@company.com"` in `initialize`.

Comment: and one more question, how can I automatically attribute a `user_id` on my sqlserver database to my ldap `user` so he can use the rest of the app? I get the current error when I log in: `Couldn't find User with 'id'=my.name@company.com` on line `@current_user ||= User.find(session[:user_id]) if session[:user_id]`

Comment: Y@AnroDeodo You will need to check if user exists as well in your db (no auth needed there) and use its id, i'll update my answer to show that.

Comment: in the `else` statment can I make it create a `user_id` for that `NumeroEmpregado` if one is non-existent? If so, how?

Comment: @AnroDeodo Yes , you can use `find_or_create_by` (see the [docs](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActiveRecord/Relation.html#method-i-find_or_create_by)), but you will need to provide all required user attributes in order to create a `User`. What attributes does `User` have?

Comment: `params.require(:user).permit(:NumeroEmpregado, :nome, :password, :password_confirmation)` This was what I was using for my previous login method, were you created user on a create user form, but now since I have the logins on the AD I don't need it anymore and would rather have my rails app creating the user_id automatically when you sign in (if there is none) if there is, just use the one assigned to that username, because I have controllers working with the `user_id` field

Comment: I added my Users_controller.rb to main code so it's easier to understand

Comment: @AnroDeodo You need to add `name` in the login form in order to create the `User`, otherwise you could only create it with `NumeroEmpregado `, but in that case (i.e. no additional attributes for `User`) there is no need for a `User` model.

Comment: Yes, I'm scraping the `NumeroEmpregado` and making it `name`, the `NumeroEmpregado` I'm hoping to get it from the AD, if so is possible

Comment: so,   `user = User.find_or_create_by_NumeroEmpregado(user)` should work right, or do I need to define something in a private method?

Comment: @AnroDeodo No private method needed, but usage should be `User.create_with(name: name).find_or_create_by(NumeroEmpregado: user)`, where `name` needs to be assigned before setting the user.

Comment: would this work? `if AuthenticateUser.new(user, password).call
      user = User.create_with(Nome: name).find_or_create_by(Nome: user)`

Comment: `undefined local variable or method 'name' for #<SessionsController:0xa1385d8>`

Comment: @AnroDeodo No, check updated answer to see an example of the correct usage. Two things two consider: 1) attributes are case sensitive, so using `Nome` or `nome` depends on how column is named in your db. 2) `create_with` adds additional attributes needed to create the object.

Comment: @AnroDeodo The error is because `name` is not defined, you need to define it (i just don't know where to get that value, that's why i don't include that specific step in my example).

Comment: it's doing: `User Load (2.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  [users].* FROM [users] WHERE [users].[nome] IS NULL  ORDER BY [users].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1  [["LIMIT", nil]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  BEGIN TRANSACTION
  User Exists (2.0ms)  EXEC sp_executesql N'SELECT  1 AS one FROM [users] WHERE [users].[NumeroEmpregado] IS NULL  ORDER BY [users].[id] ASC OFFSET 0 ROWS FETCH NEXT @0 ROWS ONLY', N'@0 int', @0 = 1  [["LIMIT", nil]]
  SQL (1.0ms)  IF @@TRANCOUNT > 0 ROLLBACK TRANSACTION`

Comment: Redirecting to root and not creating a new field in my DB table for the username

Comment: @AnroDeodo I'm not sure what the error could be, do you get any else on the log? I will highly recommend posting a new question (showing only controller code and error/log) so other users can also take a look (and improve your odds of getting a solution).

Comment: @AnroDeodo Check updated answer, i had an error which may cause the problem (should be `.find_or_create_by(NumeroEmpregado: username)` instead of `.find_or_create_by(NumeroEmpregado: user)`.

Comment: created: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45059698/upon-login-authentication-with-ldap-ad-how-do-i-create-a-user-row-if-one-is-non

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/149012/discussion-between-gerry-and-anro-deodo).