# upon login authentication with LDAP/AD how do I create a user row if one is non existent using AD records

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, ruby, authentication, ldap

Currently I have this code for my sessions_controller:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    username = params[:nome]
    password = params[:password]
    name     = username 

    if AuthenticateUser.new(username, password).call
      user = User.create_with(nome: name).find_or_create_by(nome: user)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Erro!              \nNúmero de Empregado e/ou password incorrecto(a)"
      redirect_to '/login'
     end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/index/new'
  end
end
```

What I want to do is to check if the user that I'm logging in with the `LDAP` (as shown in [my previous question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45055287/i-have-an-ldap-connection-on-my-ror-app-but-now-how-do-i-check-users-on-login)) has a field in my `users` table and if not to automatically create one with the username and attributing it an automatically `user_id` that Rails does and getting a field from the `LDAP` and putting it in my `SQLSERVER DB`, the problem is when I log in with my account It just redirects me to '/' (root) without any error notices and without creating a new row on my `database`

I'm using `SqlServer Management Studio` and my users table has the following fields: `id NumeroEmpregado nome created_at updated_at`

I want to make `NumeroEmpregado` to be automatically given from the `LDAP` (attribute in LDAP is `title`). I'll worry with that later, and I want `nome` to be the `username` given in the form:

```
 <%= form_tag '/login' do %>
  <div class="form-group">
    <div class="text">
      Número de Empregado: <br> 
      <%= text_field_tag :nome %><br>
      Password: <br>
      <%= password_field_tag :password %><br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <%= submit_tag "Submit", class: "button" %>
<% end %>
```

- How can I do this/What are the errors in my code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Update `AuthenticaeUser` to look like this:

```
class AuthenticateUser
  def self.call(*args)
    new(*args).call
  end

  def initialize(username, password)
    @username = "#{username}@company.com"
    @password = password
  end

  def call
    search_title_if_valid_user
  end

  private
  def search_title_if_valid_user
    ldap = Net::LDAP.new(
      host: server_ip_address,
      port: 389,
      base: "DC=corp,DC=com",   # change for your company values
      auth: { method: :simple, username: @username, password: @password }
    )

    ldap.search(attributes: ["title"]) if ldap.bind
  end
end
```

Then use it in your controller like this:

```
class SessionsController < ApplicationController
  def new
  end

  def create
    username = params[:nome]
    password = params[:password]

    title = AuthenticateUser.call(username, password)

    if title
      user = User.create_with(nome: username).find_or_create_by(NumeroEmpregado: title)
      session[:user_id] = user.id
      redirect_to '/'
    else
      flash[:error] = "Erro!              \nNúmero de Empregado e/ou password incorrecto(a)"
      redirect_to '/login'
     end
  end

  def destroy
    session[:user_id] = nil
    redirect_to '/index/new'
  end
end
```

This assumes that `NumeroEmpregado` value is stored in the `title` attribute within your LDAP server.

Answer (score 0):

I think you also want to re-write the creation of the user, because basically you're trying to create it first, and the calling find or create again. You can have it all in the same method, hence it's `find_or_create_by`. You probably want to make sure the user was created/exists as well (`.persisted?` will return true for either).

```
if AuthenticateUser.new(username, password).call
  user = User.find_or_create_by(nome: username)
  if user.persisted?
    session[:user_id] = user.id
    redirect_to '/'
  else
    #...
  end
else
  flash[:error] = "Erro!              \nNúmero de Empregado e/ou password incorrecto(a)"
  redirect_to '/login'
end
```

Comment: @AnroDeodo Yes, you can, using `user.persisted?` is a good way to catch failed created users.

Comment: The only catch here is that `User.find_or_create_by(nome: username)` will fail every time if additional attributes are needed in the model. If so, thats where `create_with` comes handy.

Comment: Actually since now it will save another field,  the two calls make sense. And since now the abstraction gerry introduced checks first if the LDAP user exists in the external system (and assuming no duplicate users can exist in that system) it shouldn't be needed as long as your validations are correctly set for the user. On the first case you showed, since you were doing `create_with :nome`, and then `create_or_find_by :nome` it was unnecessary.